# Where is the trading system?

Tags: rocket-league

I saw that developers of rocket league said that  rocket league has player to player cosmetic trading system. Problem is that I cant find button for that. Anyone knows where is it and how to use it if that even exists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done by completing the following:

1. Invite the player to your party.
2. Navigate to the player's name in the bottom left portion of the menu.
3. Choose the "Invite to Trade" option.
4. This will bring up the trade menu where you're able to see what items are available for trading, what you're willing to trade along with the other member.
5. A request must be made by one player and the other player must accept the request for a successful trade.

**Note: This cannot be done with a split screen party member.**

**Here is a video as a source:**

Answer (score 3):

You can trade by:

- Inviting the person you want to trade with to a party
- Click on said persons name (in the bottom left of the screen)
- From there you will see an 'invite to trade' option pop up.
- Click on this option and the person will receive a message that invites them to trade.
- If the person accepts the invite, you will be transferred to a 'trading' screen in which you can make a trade.